# Dropdown menu routing not working - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have implemented following dropdown menu

```
<NavLink activeClassName="navLinkIsActive" to="turnUp-dashboard" id="dropdown-hover">
    <div className="w3-dropdown-hover">
        <StyledText className="navbar-item w3-button w3-black">
            TurnUp Dashboard
        </StyledText>
        <div className="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">
            <a to="" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">Simulation</a>
            <a to="/DashboardH" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">History</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</NavLink>
```

For the dropdown, I used the stylesheet of w3 because I am familiar with that. 
But the link for the item "History" is not working.

**`StyledText`** and **`NavLink`** are react classes.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Try this, `<a href="/DashboardH" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">History</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Link from react-router-dom instead of anchor tag.**

```
<Link to="/DashboardH" className="w3-bar-item w3-button">History </Link>
```

**Route providing**

```
<Route path="/DashboardH" component={History} />
```